# jQuery wrap only around string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on some jQuery code to turn:

```html
<blockquote>
  Quote
  <cite>Author</cite>
</blockquote>
```

into:

```html
<blockquote>
  <q>Quote</q>
  <cite>Author</cite>
</blockquote>
```

So far I've been trying to loop through each block quote, detach the `<cite>` element, use jQueries wrapInner function to wrap the remaining string in the `<q>` element, then reattach the `<cite>` element.

The ultimate goal is to do something like this `<http://24ways.org/2005/swooshy-curly-quotes-without-images/>`. Except using jQuery to automate the placement of `.bqstart` & `.bqend`.

Comment: Are you asking how to wrap a `q` tag around the non-marked-up string within a `blockquote` element?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Here is something approximating what is going on in your URL: http://jsfiddle.net/532At/2 Note the `.bqstart`/`.bqend` are not really necessary; this could be done directly with `q:before` and `q:after`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the `nodeType` property of the `childNode`s, if the value is 3, then the node is a `textNode`.

```
$('blockquote').contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
}).wrap('<q/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `blockquote` elements all have the same structure it's pretty easy to do. 
Providing the answer in plain JS/ no jQuery. Benefit over string methods like Faiz' answer is that it's non-destructive, so it's (marginally) faster (browser doesn't need to rebuild the DOM) & it preserves data bound to the element (ie, event listeners)

```
function wrapQuotes() {
  var quotes = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote'), quote, qEl;
  for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
    quote = quotes[i].firstChild;
    // if the structure is always the same, you can leave out this if clause
    if (quote.nodeType === 3) { 
      qEl = document.createElement('q');
      qEl.appendChild(quote); // or .childNodes[0]
      quotes[i].insertBefore(qEl, quotes[i].firstChild);
    }
  }
}
wrapQuotes();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a little bit here, but are you wanting:

```
$('blockquote')
    .wrapInner('<q>')
    .find('cite')
    .each(function ea(){
        $(this).appendTo($(this).closest('blockquote'));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/532At/